# UI blocked when writing 36 MB JSON file to realm Dataabase, so unable to show progress

Tags: android, json, performance, realm, progressdialog

I am trying to parse a local JSON file i.e. 36 mb large into realm database. I am also trying to show progress bar while doing it. But it is not showing. I then used timer to start realm task after a second, this time progress dialog starts but hangs after a second. I even tried asynch realm task but issue persists.

```
RealmAsyncTask transaction = realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
        }
    }, null);

// configuration change ... 

public void onStop () {
if (transaction != null && !transaction.isCancelled()) {
    transaction.cancel();
   }
}
```

Guys, find any solution regarding this.

Comment: If you don't want to block the UI thread, then stop doing UI-thread synchronous transaction (`executeTransaction()` on UI thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an async transaction instead

```
showProgressbar();
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // Import data
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
      hideProgressbar();
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
      hideProgressbar();
    }
});
```